# How do I prevent input to a text area once the pixel width of another element is reached?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a `textarea` (`#stamptext`), a preview area (`#stamptextbox`) and a `span` within `#stamptextbox` called `#previewtext`.

I need to prevent further entry into `#stamptext` when `#previewtext` reaches the pixel width of `#stamptextbox`.

**I cannot limit by character count.**

I know how to test for the condition (see code below) but not how to prevent further entry into the `textarea`.

Any input greatly appreciated.

```
  $('#stamptext').keyup(function(e){
        if($('#previewtext').width() >= $("#stamptextbox").width()){
            [what do I do here!?]
        }
   });
```

**edit** The user needs to be able to delete text from the box once the limit is reached, just not add more. I should have made this clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give it a `disabled` attribute, set to `true`:

```
$(this).prop('disabled', true);
```

> Wouldn't this prevent the user from then deleting what they've added? Admittedly I did not make it clear that this was necessary.

In that case, you can instead give it a `maxlength` attribute set to the number of characters currently held in the textbox:

```
$(this).attr('maxlength', $(this).val().length);
```

Note that you'll want to use `removeAttr('maxlength')` to get rid of the `maxlength` attribute when the conditions of your `if` statement are not satisfied.

#### Demo

This demo obviously doesn't do what your code does, but it shows how this prevents the user typing more text into the `textarea` after a certain condition is met. Do note that I've used the `input` event instead of the `keyup` event, as this handles more text entry cases (i.e. pasting text in through the context menu wouldn't fire a `keyup`).

In your code, the `maxlength` value would be dynamically determined, but here I'm using a fixed length check on the number of characters (`10`).

```js
$(function() {
  $('textarea').on('input', function() {
    var len = $(this).val().length;
    
    if (len == 10)
      $(this).attr('maxlength', len);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea></textarea>
```

Comment: Wouldn't this prevent the user from then deleting what they've added? Admittedly I did not make it clear that this was necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Use `event.preventDefault();`, like this:

```
$('#stamp-text').keydown(function(e){
    var code = e.keyCode || e.which;
    if($('#previewtext').width() >= $("#stamptextbox").width() && code != 8
        && code != 46) //delete or backspace
        e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: Now this has the correct effect, but prevents the user from deleting the content once the limit is reached.